# Does there exist a non-trivial, associative Lie algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

In a Linear Algebra text I'm reading the author states that a Lie Algebra $K$ is non-associative unless we have $[x, y] = 0$ for all $x, y \in K$ (i.e, if $[v, [u, w]] = [[v, u], w]$ for all $v, u, w \in K$, then $[x, y] = 0$ for all $x, y \in K$). Is this true? Because I don't see it. By the way, the text is 'The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know' by Johnathan S. Golan. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not true.

Start with the Jacobi identity: $[a,[b,c]] + [b,[c,a]] + [c,[a,b]] = 0.$

If $[,]$ is associative then $[a,[b,c]] = [[a,b],c] = -[c,[a,b]]$, so $[b,[c,a]] = 0$ for all $a,b,c$.  In other words, all brackets must lie in the center of the Lie algebra.

Conversely, if we define a bilinear skew-symmetric $[,]$ for which $[b,[c,a]]=0$ holds identically, then we have a Lie algebra because the Jacobi identity is trivially satisfied.

So take a three dimensional vector space with basis $x,y,z$ and define $[x,y]=z$ and $[x,z]=0$ and $[y,z]=0$.  This gives a counterexample.

It is true (and we have proved above), that if the Lie bracket is associative then we have $[[a,b],c] = [a,[b,c]] = 0$ for all $a,b,c$.

Comment: +1 was there. Just remarking that the 3-dimensional Lie algebra you use as a counterexample is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of upper triangular 2x2 matrices (bracket= the usual commutator). This may make it easier to believe that it **is** a Lie algebra.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I think you meant $3\times3$ strictly upper triangular matrices.

Comment: @Marc: Indeed, sorry about that :-)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162019/

Comment: Just a note: if the characteristic of the field is not 2, then anticommutativity with associativity already imply the Jacobi identity; if we denote the product by ∗ then the commutator for this product, $[x,y]_∗:=x∗y−y∗x$, satisfies Jacobi identity. But$ [x,y]_∗=2x∗y$ by anticommutativity, so $x∗y=1/2[x,y]_∗$ is a Lie product. Therefore every associative and anticommutative algebra $(A,+,∗)$ over a field of characteristic not 2 satisfies $A*A*A=0$.