# An example of a Lie bracket

Tags: lie-algebras

Suppose we are given a vector space $V$ equipped with a bilinear form $[,]:V\times V\to V$ such that

$$[x,y]=h, \quad \text{and} \quad [x,h]=0=[y,h]$$
for any $x,y$ and $h$ in $V$.

> > How can we show that this bilinear form defines a Lie bracket on $V$?

A Lie bracket has to be antisymmetric meaning that $[x,y]=-[y,x]$ and satisfies in the Jacobi identity $ [x, [y, z]] + [y, [z, x]] + [z, [x, y]] = 0$.

Many thanks!

Comment: @Gae. S Yes, sorry. We can say there exists $h$. My main problem is with the antisymmetric part.

Comment: Your conditions don't make sense "for any $x,y,h$" (if you mean e.g. "for all $x,y,h$ we have ..." then that forces $V=0$). Maybe instead you mean to use $h$ just as an abbreviation for $[x,y]$?

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobi identity here is trivial, because each term in it is zero. We have $[x,[y,z]]=0$ for all $x,y,z$, since the Heisenberg Lie algebra is $2$-step nilpotent - see your previous question and the answers to it:

[Associative Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385395/associative-lie-algebra)

So we have
$$ [x, [y, z]] + [y, [z, x]] + [z, [x, y]] = 0+0+0.$$

By convention, only the Lie bracket $[x,y]=h$ is given, with the implicit understanding that $[y,x]=-h$. Here $(x,y,h)$ is a basis of the Heisenberg Lie algebra.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But can you please explain a bit more about the antisymmetric part?

Comment: There is nothing more to explain.  Since the Lie bracket is antisymmetric, it is enough to say what $[x,y]$ is. Then we know that $[y,x]=-[x,y]$. It is enough to specify this for a basis of the Lie algebra. For the Heisenberg Lie algebra, a basis is $(x,y,h)$ with Lie bracket(s) $[x,y]=h$. We even omit zero brackets.