# How can I prove an associative ring is commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Given an associative ring, $(R, +, \cdot)$, and the bracket operation defined by $[a,b] = ab-ba$ how can I prove $[a,[b,c]] = 0$ for $a,b,c \in R$? I think the ring must be commutative, so $a(bc-cb) = (bc-cb)a$ and thus $=0$, but I do not know how to prove the ring is commutative.

Comment: Commutativity is stronger than that. You only need the image 9f the bracket to commute with all of $R.$

Comment: The property may hold in noncommutative rings (if the ring is commutative then you already have $[a,b]=0$ for all $a,b\in R$); but I don't think the property holds for *all* rings, so you must have some extra condition.

Comment: If $R$ is commutative, then $[a,b] = 0$ for all $a$ and $b$, so the identity $[a,[b,c]]=0$ is trivial. But not every associative ring is commutative, and there are associative rings in which the identity does not hold. Did you maybe mean to prove  the [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) instead?

Comment: In a nilpotent group of class $2$, every commutator is central. There is no analogous name for **rings** with every commutator central, however.

Comment: [Non-commutative ring such that $[[x,y],z]=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2162019/29335)

Comment: In $\mathbb Z\langle x,y,z\rangle$, $[x,[y,z]]\neq 0$, so this doesn't hold for all noncommutative rings. On the other hand, [these solutions show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2162019/29335) a nontrivial noncommutative ring CAN have all commutators central.